# Flutter: Why this streambuilder is not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a Password/E-mail login, but i'm struggling with the user register.

My problem is, when I create the user, my auth state handler switchs to my home page, as it should... But when app tries to show the username or photo, these are null and crash.

This is my handler (which works perfectly fine with Google Login):

```
handleAuthState() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return const HomeScreen();
    } else {
      return const LoginScreen();
    }
  },
);
```

}

I've tried to handle this nulls using ternary ifs, example:

```
Text(
 FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName == null? "-"
 : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName!style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
)
```

But, when I add this, streambuilder stops working and doesn't switch pages anymore. This is my third day in a row trying to find out how solve this and I wasn't able.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: what do you see if you `print(snapshot)`?

Comment: Hey! @pskink, Ty for your response, here's snapshot.data https://imgur.com/a/SrcZNfb

Comment: And here's snapshot https://imgur.com/a/JQBR4Jh

Comment: Here's snapshot https://imgur.com/a/JQBR4Jh @pskink

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<User?>(ConnectionState.active, User(displayName: null, email: dasdafa@gmail.com, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-11-30 14:42:51.354Z, lastSignInTime: 2022-11-30 14:42:51.354Z), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: dasdafa@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: dasdafa@gmail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: y1iRKIdyMvgyRbPfxG427QhaNlF3), null, null)